# When using .jsp's view spring mvc, and passing ModelAndView, how to output model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I have a modelandView like:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

mav.setViewName("index");
mav.addObject("message", "hello, world");

return mav;
```

In index.jsp, how do I output the value of "message"?

And what if I passed in:

```
mav.addObject("user", currentUser);
```

It seems the docs jump straight into forms handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can output it by using the EL language like this:

${message} and ${user}

In your jsp. Spring with automatically scan the jsp and process these and other EL expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<c:if test="${message!=null}">
        ${message}
    </c:if>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question it is better to include an explanation of how it answers the question in order that this answer is useful to future visitors of the site

Answer (score 0):

1- If you are using the old **JSP 1.2** descriptor, defined by DTD for example
web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
//...
</web-app>
```

The **EL is disabled** or ignored by default, you have to enable it manually, so that it will outputs the value store in the `message` model.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
</head>
<body>
           ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

2- In **JSP 2.0**

If you are using the standard **JSP 2.0** descriptor, defined by w3c schema ,for example
web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
//...
</web-app>
```

The **EL is enabled** by default, and you should see the value stored in the `message` model, which is `hello world`.